# How can I get bug reporting help?

Tags: launchpad, bug-reporting

Often, I find issues with the internals of Ubuntu and I don't know how to effectively assign the bug to the right project/audience.

Take [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/656855) for example, regarding multiple monitor support. I'd like to file this bug against Gnome, but I don't know which of the *many* Gnome projects apply here (or is it actually a problem with X? or gtk?). I can't even search for gnome-related projects or packages, as Launchpad complains:

> Too many matches. Please try to narrow your search.

I've tried asking on #ubuntu and #ubuntu+1 but received no help due to the very high amount of ongoing activity: IRC just doesn't scale.

As a result I had to mark the bug generically against Ubuntu and now it's just one of a dozen emails that the poor souls subscribed to the project receive on a hourly basis. I doubt the bug will get any attention this way.

**How can I effectively target a bug with non-frontend components of Ubuntu?** Where can I get help with targeting such bugs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/FindRightPackage) should help you narrow down the right package. For bug triaging help find someone in the [Bug Squad](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BugSquad/Contacts) or ask on their mailing list or in #ubuntu-bugs.

The bugsquad has regular meetings and can probably find you a mentor if you want to help (and join!). For reference here's the [Bug Triaging Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/HowToTriage/).