# How to report a bug in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma

I need to report a bug against plasma-widgets-workspace that got installed for Kubuntu. This question is not generic, is related to a family of KDE packages.

The "regular"

```
ubuntu-bug plasma-widgets-workspace
```

complains that:

```
The problem cannot be reported:

This is not an official Ubuntu package. Please remove any third party package and try again.
```

I understand the Kubuntu is no Ubuntu, but I am not using any third party repo.
The package description itself says:

```
Package: plasma-widgets-workspace
Priority: optional
Section: universe/kde
Installed-Size: 2261
Maintainer: Kubuntu Developers <kubuntu-devel@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian Qt/KDE Maintainers <debian-qt-kde@lists.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Source: kde-workspace
Version: 4:4.11.8-0ubuntu6
Replaces: kde-workspace-data (<< 4:4.10.80)
Provides: notification-daemon
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), libkdecore5 (>= 4:4.5.86), libkdeui5 (>= 4:4.4.95), libkdewebkit5 (>= 4:4.4.0), libkio5 (>= 4:4.4.0), libkunitconversion4 (>= 4:4.4.0), libplasma3 (>= 4:4.7.0), libplasmaclock4abi4 (= 4:4.11.8-0ubuntu6), libqt4-declarative (>= 4:4.7.0~rc1), libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3), libqt4-xml (>= 4:4.5.3), libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1), libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta2), libqtwebkit4, libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1), libx11-6, libxcomposite1 (>= 1:0.3-1), libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1), libxfixes3, libxrender1, plasma-dataengines-workspace (= 4:4.11.8-0ubuntu6), akonadi-server, kdepim-runtime
Breaks: kde-workspace-data (<< 4:4.10.80)
Filename: pool/universe/k/kde-workspace/plasma-widgets-workspace_4.11.8-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb
Size: 438066
MD5sum: 9fafe2830c05ab4e0f0ed7efc46cdd7a
SHA1: 66f538606953248004a0faca86c74c6cce250add
SHA256: 9596cafbfe82a5788e5ff79946544b5446ac968da936eaad01dd4a9ca55c92a7
Description-en: plasma widgets and containments for the KDE Plasma Workspace
 This package contains standard Plasma widgets and containments shipped in the
 KDE base workspace module. They provide such basic desktop functionality as
 the panel, task manager, application laucher, clock and more. The default KDE
 Workspace is a combination of these visual components.
 .
 This package also includes the default animator used by the main KDE Plasma
 Desktop shell.
 .
 This package is part of the KDE base workspace module.
Description-md5: 4161ffad00006dbc380517a452d10b9b
Homepage: http://www.kde.org/
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
Supported: 5y
Task: kubuntu-desktop, kubuntu-full, kubuntu-active, kubuntu-active-desktop, kubuntu-active-full, kubuntu-active
```

In Kubuntu.org I can be part of the Bug Squad, discuss, propose ... whatever else but cannot report bugs!

Hints?

P.S.
This is not the same as [question no.5347](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5347/how-can-i-get-bug-reporting-help) as this is not a "too many matches" issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get bug reporting help?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5347/how-can-i-get-bug-reporting-help)

Comment: You can always get on Launchpad and do it the old-fashioned way.

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste Which old-fashioned way?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I thought you were familiar with Launchpad. I meant that you could get on it at http://launchpad.net, look up the package, and just fill out all of the bug report information in your browser.

Comment: I do am familiar. Nonetheless I, like almost everyone else, rely on ubuntu-bug script for reports.

Answer (score 1):

You can use their bug reporting website [click here](https://bugs.kde.org/)

Comment: The problem with submitting bugs 'upstream' is that the bug may not be present in the KDE source, it may be a issue with the Ubuntu packaged version (but its still OK). There are URLs for reporting bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kde-workspace/+filebug (or asking questions: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kde-workspace/+addquestion) provided on the [package's page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/plasma-widgets-workspace) though.

Comment: The bug is very likely related to Kubuntu, not KDE.

Comment: @Wilf The bug link redirects to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs